# set fill-column in org-capture notes

Tags: org-mode, hooks, org-capture

I'm trying to customize the `fill-column` value for `org-add-note` when adding notes to an Org TODO (e.g., `C-c C-z`).

I have tried to add the following to the `org-add-note` function (this seems reasonable from the `add-hook` documentation).

```
(add-hook #'org-add-note (lambda () (setq fill-column 72)))
```

However, it doesn't seem to work, I get the following in the `*Messages*` buffer:

> Fill column set to 79 (was 70)

Since it *was* 70 and no other messages indicating otherwise, this tells me it was never 72, which means there's nothing else in my configuration overriding the hook value.

Setting the global `org-mode` `fill-column` won't work since this customization is to work around Org-mode indenting the notes in the drawers of the TODO, which takes off about 5 spaces already.  That is, setting a custom `fill-column` value for any buffer in `Org` mode doesn't solve the problem.

Perhaps the solution is have a function that checks the buffer name?  If the buffer name is "`*Org Note*`" in `Org` mode, set to `fill-column` to 72, otherwise, leave it alone or use the "default".

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually hooks have names that end in `-hook` or `-functions`, so `org-add-note` is probably not the name of the hook you need to use.

Based on looking at the code, I'd suggest you use something like:

```
(add-hook 'org-log-buffer-setup-hook #'my-set-fill-column)
(defun my-set-fill-column () (setq-local fill-column 72))
```

Comment: Is there any particularly reason for `defun` over a lambda?  Extensibility?
Actually, why does this work with a named function and not a lambda?

Comment: Turns out my issue with respect to named functions versus lambda and working and not working turns out to be `setq-local` versus `setq`.  They both work, I will need to research the difference between those two.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: No, the only important difference is the name of the hook (i.e. `org-log-buffer-setup-hook` instead of `org-add-note`).